# Unable to import SGD and Adam from 'keras.optimizers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Trying to run---**
`from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam`,
**I get this error---**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\usn\Downloads\CNN-Image-Denoising-master ------after the stopping\CNN-Image-Denoising-master\CNN_Image_Denoising.py", line 15, in <module>
>     from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
> ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'keras.optimizers'

**as well as this error, if I remove the SGD from import statement---**

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers'

I can't find a single solution for this.
I have Keras and TensorFlow installed. I tried running the program in a virtualenv (no idea how that would help, but a guide similar to what I want mentioned it) but it still doesn't work. If anything, virtualenv makes it worse because it doesn't recognize any of the installed modules. I am using Python 3.9. Running the program in cmd because all the IDEs just create more trouble.

I am stumped. My knowledge of Python is extremely basic; I just found this thing on GitHub. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23728:

> from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
>
> instead of :
>
> from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

It worked for me.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked but tbh I couldn't make head or tail of it. The only thing that could be a solution (from what I inferred at that time) was the last few lines written by OP himself. But I am confused as to how I can use it in my code. I'll keep trying to understand it. Will update if I figure it out.

Comment: Ok @George, I think it might have worked. I am uncertain because I made some changes before in order to put this one error aside and focus on others. But hopefully I put everything back to how it was and if I did, then this error is solved. Thanks for pointing out that specific line. I had missed it when reading that thread myself!

Comment: This is not actually a solution, because keras.optimizers is broken, its a problem in the code, and it will affect tf.keras once the migration to independent keras is complete.

Comment: "keras" package was moved under "tensorflow" and maintained there. For this specific case, standalone "keras" package is no longer maintained. Instead, "tensorflow" maintains all "keras" subpackages deemed to improve TF functionality. So, it is the solution.

It's the same case with "beautifulsoup" and "beautifulsoup4". "beautifulsoup" is not broken, it is discontinued.

Answer (score 49):

This simple modification fixed my problem:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of :

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

write :

```
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2
```

and then use it like this:

```
sgd = gradient_descent_v2.SGD(...)
```

--

To the people suggesting using

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

it only works if you use TensorFlow throughout your whole program. If you want to use keras specifically, importing tensorflow.keras.optimizers won't work as it will conflict with other parts of your program. In this case use my solution instead.

Comment: That's right. Also, if you'd like to use Adam, then you need to use the `from keras.optimizers import adam_v2` statement. Then, use call the constructor through `adam_v2.Adam`. Hope this contributes to the this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Write :

```
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2
```

instead of :

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

Answer (score 0):

`from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical`

It works just as well for to_categorical.